# How to remove StartIsBack without access to system?

Tags: windows-8.1, start-menu

[StartIsBack](http://startisback.com/) made my system unusable (start menu is constantly flashing, can't access anything). Therefore, I can't remove this program via uninstall. How can I remove it from system files via other system?

Comment: Can you get to run? Try running ‘StartIsBackCfg /uninstall’ from Run dialog

Comment: You can also run the installer again.  If its already installed you should be given an option to repair or uninstall the application.

Comment: @Psycogeek: Post that as an answer and get my upvotes. Tip for those searching for it: It's under %LOCALAPPDATA%\StartIsBack (enter that in the address bar anywhere)

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** You can disable the auto-startup of *StartIsBack* program from `msconfig.exe`*(C:\Windows\System32\msconfig.exe)* or disable it using Microsoft's [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and reboot, so *StartIsBack* won't be loaded, and you can uninstall it easily.
(or)

 **Option 2:** You can uninstall that program in safe mode:

*Note: These are the steps to boot into safe mode in Windows 8 and Windows 8.1*

1.press the Power button at the Windows login screen or in the Settings charm. Then, press and hold the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key on your keyboard and click Restart.
[image]

2.Windows asks you to choose an option. Press Troubleshoot.
[image]

3.In the Troubleshoot screen, press Advanced options.
[image]

4.In the Advanced options screen, press Startup Settings.
[image]

5.You are informed that you are about to restart in order to change several Windows options, including enabling Safe Mode. Press Restart.
[image]

6.Your computer restarts again and displays nine startup settings, including Safe Mode, Safe Mode with Networking and Safe Mode with Command Prompt
[image]

7.Press the <kbd>F4</kbd> key on your keyboard to enable Safe Mode, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 now boot to safe mode. Now you can uninstall the "StartIsBack" program and restart the pc normally.

Comment: StartIsBack registers a DLL which can't be disabled with msconfig or autoruns

Answer (score 0):

In safe mode, you may try to rename the `StartIsBack64.dll` and `StartIsBack32.dll` as admin in the specific program folder, therefore StartIsBack won't be able to start. Then when Windows starts normally you'll get your normal tile view back and try to uninstall StartIsBack the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

Just hold esc while logging in to disable it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Open a command prompt and enter "control" (without quotes)  to open control panel then got to programs and uninstall startisback.